# Linq Query to check if the records are all the same

Tags: c#, linq

I am very much new to the Linq queries. I have the set of records in the csv which is like below

```
ProdID,Name,Color,Availability
P01,Product1,Red,Yes
P02,Product2,Blue,Yes
P03,Product1,Yellow,No
P01,Product1,Red,Yes
P04,Product1,Black,Yes
```

I need to check for the Names of the each product and if its is not the same in all the records then I need to send an error message.I know the below query is used to find the duplicates in the records but not sure how can I modify it check if it all has the same values.

```
ProductsList.GroupBy(p => p.Name).Where(p => p.Count() > 1).SelectMany(x => x);
```

Comment: Just change the `GroupBy` to use whichever fields you want to be part of the check

Comment: So you want to check `ProductList` to see if every item in the list has the same name?

Comment: @maccettura yes

Comment: I believe I helped you with that query on a previous question.  You use this in a `foreach` right?  Do you wan't to throw an error on each iteration if the item is not like the other?  Or do you want to check all the records before you even get to your `foreach` statement?

Comment: @maccettura I need to check each record and see if all the records  name field are same as the first record name field. If it is not the same then I need to insert them in to the database like the other problem

Comment: @KeithS has the best answer for your problem in my opinion.

Comment: @maccettura I getting error `foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'bool' because 'bool' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'` when I use them in the foreach

Comment: Use it before the foreach.  It returns a `bool` so use it in an `if` statement

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
   var first = myObjects.First();
   bool allSame = myObjects.All(x=>x.Name == first.Name);
```

Enumerable.All() will return true if the lambda returns true for all elements of the collection. In this case we're checking that every object's Name property is equal to the first (and thus that they're all equal to each other; the transitive property is great, innit?). You can one-line this by inlining myObjects.First() but this will slow performance as First() will execute once for each object in the collection. You can also theoretically Skip() the first element as we know it's equal to itself.

Comment: I am getting error when I am using them in the foreach loop like `var firstPdt = ProductsList.First();
            foreach ( var pdtecord in ProductsList.All( s=> s.Name != firstPdt.Name))`  like `foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'bool' because 'bool' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'`

Comment: That's because All() returns a Boolean representing the answer to the question, "Is the specified criteria true for every item in the collection?". It does not filter the results to return only the ones for which the criteria is true; to do that, you'd use `Where()`.

Comment: Would crash for empty collection - FirstOrDefault won't harm here.

Comment: True, but it might also have unwanted behavior; All() returns true for an empty sequence, which may not be what the OP wants in that situation. Probably best overall to check for Any() first and return the desired result if Any() returns false.

Answer (score 0):

**UPD after author comment:**

To know all the records that are not having the same name as the first record:

```
var firstName = ProductsList[0].Name;
var differentNames = ProductsList.Where(p => p.Name != firstName);
```

Another option (just to have all other names): `ProductsList.Select(p => p.Name).Where(n => n != firstName).Distinct()`

**Old version**

So, if there are at least two different names then you should return an error?

LINQ way: `return ProductsList.Select(p => p.Name).Distinct().Count() <= 1`

More optimizied way:

```
if (ProductsList.Count == 0)
  return true;

var name = ProductsList[0].Name;

for (var i = 1; i < ProductsList.Count; i++)
{
  if (ProductsList[i].Name != name)
    return false;
}

return true;
```

Comment: What makes you think the second method is "more optimised" here?

Comment: Because if we have 10 different names then LINQ way will iterate all rows anyway. But actually we can stop iteration when we find just 2nd name.

Comment: That doesn't mean your method is faster though.

Comment: It depends on input data but it is definitely faster if we have something like [name1, name2, ... another one million of items ....]

Comment: Yes, it may well be, but the only way to say for sure is to benchmark both methods.

Comment: @oryol when I am using this in my for loop like `foreach (var pdtrecord in ProductsList.Select(p => p.Name).Distinct().Count() <= 1)` because I need to insert them in to database with error message. But the Linq is throwing error saying `foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'bool' because 'bool' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'`

Comment: The Linq query is slower, but it's not a fair comparison because this usage of Count() is a day-one no-no. All() can be used to give an equivalent answer, while stopping enumeration as soon as a non-matching element is found. The use of Distinct() makes Count() itself work faster, but then you're offloading the full enumeration to Distinct() which runs linearly with some additional overhead.

Comment: @ the issue is I need to know all the records that are not having the same name as the first records

Answer (score 0):

if I understand correctly you want to check if product exists in the list

```
using System.Linq;

private bool ItemExists(string nameOfProduct) { 
  return ProductsList.Any(p=> p.Name== nameOfProduct);
}
```